# Return 0 if $sum is null (aggregation framework)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

So I'm using aggregation framework to sum some results in given time blocks.
My question is how do I return `count: 0` every time if there was no results in the time block.

So let's say in first ten seconds my `count: 7` in next ten seconds `count: 2` and then if in the third time block there was nothing I would like aggregate function to return `count: 0`

Below simple summing operation:

```
$group: {
  _id: 1,
  count: { $sum: 1 }
}
```

I have tried using `$ifNull`, but it didn't work for me:

```
$group: {
  _id: 1,
  count: { $sum: { $ifNull: [ $count, 0 ] } }
}
```

Comment: What does your document look like?

Comment: I'm aggregating number of documents, so the `$sum` sums all of the documents in the DB in given time block (e.g. 10secs)

Comment: I see that. So what are the previous steps in the aggregation pipeline, before you do the `$group`?

Comment: @JuanCarlosFarah it's extra question to the previous I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823782/time-series-and-aggregation-framework-mongo so the code looks like Leonid's answer in that question (more or less)

Comment: One thing I can think of is that the value is not null

Comment: @knowbody, how can that value be null? `$group` will group by the specified id, which in this case is `$delta`, right? If there is a value for `$delta`, then there is a count. If there isn't, then the `_id` will be null, but there will still be a count. Is that what you're referring to, when the `_id` is null?

Comment: I think so... I thought it makes `count` null

Comment: @JuanCarlosFarah so how do I do it?

Comment: @knowbody, just to be clear. Where are you seeing the `null` values? Are you seeing them as an output to the following `$project`? `$project: { time: "$_id", count: 1, _id: 0 }` I got that from the answer to your other question.

Comment: I don't get any `null`s it's just what I thought. It looks like this points (which suppose to be 0s) are just skipped

Comment: @knowbody: Can you add to your question some sample data and the expected output? I hope i can arrive at the correct solution then

Comment: please close as I didn't ask the question precisely. The other question I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039406/skipped-count-0-in-aggregate-function is more relevant and has the correct answer.
Thanks.