# How can I remove the matching element from the array in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So I'm using aggregation framework to sum some results.
My question is how do I avoid returning `count: 0` every time if there was the sum result equal to 0.

I want to display only `count: 20` and to get rid of the other `count: 0`.

[image]

Links:

- [ifNull helps to populate a null entry with a desired value](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)
- [something similar but the reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24955292/return-0-if-sum-is-null-aggregation-framework)

Comment: Part of the reason why image inclusion has a restriction is that we kind of hate them and prefer you to show your code. In this case, rather show the "full" code of your current aggregation and possibly a sample document or two, as well as expected output (all in standard JSON notation, which is just text) so someone has a clue what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is remove a field from a document in the pipeline based on the value of the field. I do not believe this is possible with the aggregation framework (as of 2.6). It seems like a non-problem though, since it should be trivial to ignore the `count : 0` results wherever you are using them. A full aggregation pipeline would be helpful to see, because there may be modifications earlier in the pipeline that would prevent any `count` fields being created with a value of 0, solving the problem from the other direction, so to speak.